# How do I complete the Invitation image?

Tags: the-king-of-fighters-13

In the gallery menu there's an Invitation image that is filled as I play. How do I complete it? Are there events that unlock each part or is it just the more I play the more it gets discovered?

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing on XBox 360, the invitation image unlocks as you get the achievements.